# SQLite Shows Data When Accessed Via URL

Tags: php, html, sql, sqlite

I am creating a website in which users can log in a share pictures. The problem is, when I type in domain.com/database.sqlite, it shows a bunch of question marks and some of the data stored in the database. How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: use htaccess or server configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could configure your server as the others suggested but it would be better if you could move the database out of the public directory. That way if you upgrade the server and your settings get changed the database still can't be accessed.